# Access dataTask from inside completionHandler

Tags: swift

I am using `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` to access an API which, on certain circumstances, won't respond immediately. I also need to cancel pending requests on certain conditions.

My current implementation uses the `completionHandler` approach and multiple requests can happen in parallel. This makes it very inconvenient to change the pattern to a delegate.

What I am trying is to store every pending task in a set, and then remove the task from the set once they are done. The problem is accessing the return of the dataTask from inside the completion handler seems very cumbersome, to a point I am not sure this is even correct.

```swift
class API {
  private var tasks: Set<URLSessionTask> = []

  func sendRequest(path: String, body: [String: Any], completionHandler: @escaping @Sendable (APIResponse) -> Void) {
    var request = // ... create request

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { [self] data, response, error in
      // ... handle response

      tasks.remove(task)
    }

    tasks.insert(task)
    task.resume()
  }

  func cancelAllTasks() {
    for task in tasks {
      task.cancel()
      tasks.remove(task)
    }
  }
}
```

I either get a compiler error `Closure captures 'task' before it is declared` or a warning `'task' mutated after capture by sendable closure`.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your completion handler tries to reference the task which isn't yet defined when you create the completion handler.

Assuming your requests are unique, you could use a dictionary of your data tasks keyed by their URLRequest. Then add a method `taskComplete(forRequest:)` to your API class. Have your completion handler send that message to the API class.

The API class could remove the task using the request as a key (I checked. `URLRequest` is `Hashable`.

If your requests aren't certain to be unique, create a request struct that contains the URLTask and the Date when the task is created. The Date should make the hash of the request struct unique.